# regex string manipulation - php

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to write a function, which takes string1 as an input, grabs whatever the text is between two parameters, manipulates the grabbed string and then return the whole thing.

For example, let's say I have this: [Hi] my name [is] John.

I want to have this:

```
     <a href='Hi'>Hi</a> my name <a href='is'>is</a> John.
```

Comment: "String between two parameters" do you mean "parentheses" (or in your example, square brackets)?

Comment: (Might be interested in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]/', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $str);
```

Comment: Interesting game, who-ever finds a (rather trivial) input this fails for gets 5 internet points.

Comment: @WouterJ, this worked as a charm. What if I wanted it to be [[$string]] rather than [$string]?

Comment: then you change `\[` into `\[\[` and `\]` into `\]\]`. Or you put `[[` and `]]` into a variable and put that in the regex by using [the `.` operator](http://php.net/operators.string) and use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg-quote) to automatically escape reserved characters

Comment: @WouterJ that worked really nice as well. One last question please, your answer will be much appreciated. What if I wanted it to be {{$string}} ?

Comment: @user1726488 well, I just say that (read my comment again...)